# Modify date in org-mode html export

Tags: html, datetime, emacs, export, org-mode

I use org-mode to create a website with the html export (publish) feature.

I want to have a postamble in html with just the date (in a certain format and without hours).

Precisely, I want to have "Last update : 20 sept. 2013" at the end of my html page. And, of course, I need relative date which change according days.

I tried to achieve this by putting this code into my .emacs :

```
'(org-html-postamble t)
'(org-html-postamble-format (quote (("en" "Last update : %d"))))
```

But the result is "Last update:  " without the date.

Please tell me what I have to change into my .emacs or explain precisely another way of doing this.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `org-export-html-postamble` and `org-export-html-postamble-format`?

Comment: I don't think so (there is no org-export-html-postamble

Comment: OK, apparently I am using an old version of org-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution (thanks to org-mode mailing-list).

Paste this code into .emacs :

```
(defun my-org-html-postamble (plist)
 (format "Last update : %s" (format-time-string "%d %b %Y")))
(setq org-html-postamble 'my-org-html-postamble)
```